Understanding the proof of Classification of States in Markov Chain
Background:Let $E$ be a countable set,and $\forall x\in E$.
Define coordinate mappings $\mathbf X_n$ as follows:$$\forall w=(w_0..w_n..)\in E^{\mathbb Z_+},\mathbf X_n(w)=w_i$$Let $\mathbf P_x$ be the probability measure such that $(\mathbf X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a Markov chain with transition matrix $Q$ and $\mathbf{P}_x(\boldsymbol{X_0} =x)=1$.
($(\mathbf X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is defined to be the canonical Markov chain in my textbook)
Now define:$$\begin{aligned}&H_x=\inf\{n\geq1:\mathbf{X}_n=x\},\\&N_x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf{1}_{\{\mathbf{X}_n=x\}}.\end{aligned}$$And $\inf\varnothing:=\infty$.
I'm confused when reading a proof of Classification of States in my textbook.The theorem is as follows:

Question:I am stuck at proving the last property(blue circle).The
author says that "By applying the strong Markov property at $T$, and
the first part of the statement, we easily get that, $\mathbf{P}_{x}$
a.s. on the event $\{T<\infty\}$,we have $\mathbf{X}_n\in R_j$ for
every $n\geq T$." and leave the details to the reader. I am confused
about the details.

Edit: Maybe now I can solve it:We only need to prove the following: $$\mathbf E_{X_T}[N_{X_{n+T}}]=U(X_T,X_{n+T})>0,\mathbf P_x-a.s.$$Where $\theta_n(\mathbf X_0,..,\mathbf X_n,..)=(\mathbf X_n,\mathbf X_{n+1}...)$ is the shift operator
Using the the strong Markov property at $T$ and $\mathbf X_0=x,\mathbf P_x-a.s.$,we have: $$\begin{align}
\mathbf E_x[1_{\{\mathbf E_{\mathbf X_T}[N_{\mathbf X_{n+T}}]>0\}}]&=\mathbf E_x[1_{\{\mathbf E_{X_0}[N_{\mathbf X_{n}}]>0\}}(\theta_T)]\\&=\mathbf E_x[\mathbf E_{\mathbf X_T}[1_{\{\mathbf E_x[N_{\mathbf X_n}]>0\}}]]
\end{align}$$And $$\mathbf E_x[N_{\mathbf X_n}]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbf P_x(\mathbf X_k=\mathbf X_n)>1>0$$
Therefore $\mathbf E_{X_T}[N_{X_{n+T}}]=U(X_T,X_{n+T})>0,\mathbf P_x-a.s.$ as desired.
Is my proof right?

Note:This problem comes from Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p320

